# what does d3 brush.on("brush.chat") means?

Tags: crossfilter

I am going through the source of crossfilter.js, and I could not understand this line:

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L484

`brush.on("brushstart.chart", function() {`

Why `"brushstart.chart"` and not just `"brushstart"`? I tried and it would not work. Actually anything (`"brushstart.a"`, `"brushstart.b"` seems to work besides `"brushstart"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in [the D3 documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on):

> To register multiple listeners for the same event type, the type may be followed by an optional namespace, such as "click.foo" and "click.bar". The first part of the type ("click" for example) is used to register the event listener (using element.addEventListener()) and methods are added on the selected elements as __onclick.foo and __onclick.bar.

The code is using a namespaced event. Presumably the code uses this namespace in other places, so changing it breaks the functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Lars! You saved my day. I should have checked `selection.on`